# Copy and Paste Missing in Context Menu

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu

I'd like to add copy and paste functionality to context menu in my Flex application. After creating a separate dummy project for testing, I realize that such options (cut, copy, paste, and delete) are already available in this dummy project without any coding. Both projects are compiled using Flex 4 SDK, run in the same brower (IE) and have the same version of Flash Player (10.2.153.1). However, different context menu are displayed. Here are the difference:

Orig Project: Print, Show Redraw Regions, Debugger, Settings, Global Settings, About Flash Player...

Dummy Porject: Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Select All, Settings, Global Settings, About Flash Player...

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) you can't use such words as Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Select All as custom context menu items. So if you want to implement some copy/paste functionality via context menu in some context, other than text in text fields, you need to use some other items captions (like "Copy Object" or so).

The built in copy/paste menu items are available only for text fields. And you're right: you don't need to implement some code for that functionality.